# I have some trouble with dynamic massive in C(only C,without C++)

Tags: c, dynamic

I have to make a program that copies positive numbers from first massive to the second. With static massives I can do it but with dynamic memory I have some troubles. It didn't work. Main error is "Use of uninitialized memory" in my massives, but I think that there are more problems in the main function. Can somebody help me please.

Here is the original code:

```
int GetOutOfPos(int* arr, const unsigned int count)
{
    if (!arr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int size2 = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) 
        {
            size2++;
        }
    }

    return size2;
}


void FillingMassive(unsigned int count,int* arr) 
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 201 - 100;
    }

}

int Memory(int* arr, int* arr2,int size2, const unsigned int count)
{
    arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    arr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size2);

}


void CopPosNum(int* arr, const unsigned int count, int size2, int* arr2)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>0)
            for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
            {
                arr2[j] = arr[i];
            }
    }
}

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int* arr, *arr2;
    int size2 = 0;
    unsigned int count;
    printf("Set massive size: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &count);
    FillingMassive(count, arr);
    GetOutOfPos(arr, count);
    Memory(arr,arr2,size2,count);
    CopPosNum(arr, count, size2,arr2);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%i\n",arr[i] );
    system("pause");
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
        printf("%i\n", arr2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I changed some code, so here is what I have now:

```
int GetOutOfPos(int* arr, const unsigned int count)
{
    if (!arr)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int size2 = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) 
        {

            size2++;
        }
    }

    return size2;
}


void FillingMassive(unsigned int count,int* arr) 
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 201 - 100;
    }

}


/*int Average(int* arr, int* arr2,int size2, const unsigned int count)
{
    int Av1, Av2, s1 = 0, s2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        s1 += arr[i];
    }
    Av1 = s1 / count;

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    {
        s2 += arr2[i];
    }
    Av2 = s2 / size2;
    return Av1, Av2;

}
*/

void CopPosNum(int* arr, const unsigned int count, int size2, int* arr2)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {

            arr2[k] = arr[i];
            k++;
            //printf("%i\n",arr2[i]);

        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    int* arr, *arr2;
    int size2 = 0;
    unsigned int count;

    printf("Set massive size: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &count);


    arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * count * 8);

    FillingMassive(count, arr);

    size2 = GetOutOfPos(arr, count);

    arr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(*arr2) * size2 * 4);

    CopPosNum(arr, count, size2,arr2);


    double Av1, Av2,s1 = 0, s2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        s1 += arr[i];
    }
    Av1 = s1 / count;

    for (int i = 0; i <= size2-1; i++)
    {
        s2 += arr2[i];
    }
    Av2 = s2 / size2;



    printf("Average of first massive is: %.2f\n", Av1);
    printf("Average of second massive is: %.2f\n", Av2);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= count-1; i++)
        printf("%i\n",arr[i] );
    system("pause");
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", arr2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I take large massives, such as 100 or 1000 sometimes I'm not getting  correct results from my program, for example:
Here are some numbers of the second massive

> 60 7 85 44 69 48 87 51
>   -842150451
>   -842150451
>   -842150451
>   -842150451

The last 4 numbers are broken, why?

Comment: `FillingMassive(count, arr);` At this point your `arr` is unassigned.

Comment: I konw,but how can i fix it?

Comment: `scanf_s("%i", &count); arr = malloc(count * sizeof *arr);`

Comment: Moreover, your `Memory()` does not do what you perhaps expect. You need to pass a pointer to a pointer here.

Comment: Note that the `size2` in `GetOutOfPos` is not the same as the `size2` in `main`. So the call to `GetOutOfPos` doesn't assign a value to `size2` in `main`. To fix it you need an assignment in `main`, i.e. `size2 = GetOutOfPos(arr, count);`

Comment: Ty user.now,after if fix programm that was the second trouble

Comment: In ````Memory()````, you lose the reference of the addresses returned by malloc once the function goes out of scope.

Comment: `count` is a parameter.  Pass it in as an argument rather than reading it from stdin.